# Library Linker Propagation: is libA->libB->App the same as libA->App<-libB

Tags: c++, linker

Lets say you have 3 projects.  2 of them are static libraries.  We will call them:

- **libA**
- **libB**

The last is your application.  We will call this **App**

Suppose that **libB** calls functions in **libA** , so we link **libA**->**libB**

Suppose that **App** only calls functions from **libB**, so we link **libB**->**App**

Does this mean that **libA** is also now linked to **App?**

In short, my question is this:

**libA**->**libB**->**App** ?= **libA**->**App**<-**libB**

I'm asking because I have a third library I want to link to app, but it has some of the same function names as A. App doesn't rely on A directly, so I feel it's not ambiguous which one to use.

**Working Example**

**LibA.h**

```
#ifndef LIBA_H
#define LIBA_H
   void A_FunctionOne();
   void A_FunctionTwo();
   void A_FunctionThree();
#endif
```

**LibB.h**

```
#ifndef LIBB_H
#define LIBB_H

class LibB
{
public:
    LibB();
    void B_FunctionOne();
    void B_FunctionTwo();

};
#endif
```

**LibA2.h**

```
#ifndef LIBA_H
#define LIBA_H

void A_FunctionOne();
void A_FunctionTwo();
void A_FunctionThree();
#endif
```

**LibA.c**

```
#include "LibA.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
   void A_FunctionOne()
   {
      printf("Library A Function One\n");
   }

   void A_FunctionTwo()
   {
      printf("Library A Function Two\n");
   }

   void A_FunctionThree()
   {
      printf("Library A Function Three\n");
   }
}
```

**LibA2.c**

```
#include "LibA2.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
   void A_FunctionOne()
   {
      printf("Library A2 Function One\n");
   }

   void A_FunctionTwo()
   {
      printf("Library A2 Function Two\n");
   }

   void A_FunctionThree()
   {
      printf("Library A2 Function Three\n");
   }
}
```

**LibB.cpp**

```
#include "LibB.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "LibA.h"

LibB::LibB()
{}
void LibB::B_FunctionOne()
{
    printf("Library B, Function 1.  Calling Library A, Function 1\n");
    A_FunctionOne();
}
void LibB::B_FunctionTwo()
{
    printf("Library B, Function 2.  Calling Library B, Function 1\n");
    B_FunctionOne();
}
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "LibB.h"
#include "LibA2.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    LibB foo;
   printf("Main, calling LibB, Function 1\n");
    foo.B_FunctionOne();

   printf("Main, calling LibA2, Function 1\n");
    A_FunctionOne();
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
Project( BrainHurts )

add_library( libA STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LibA.c)
add_library( libB STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LibB.cpp )
target_link_libraries( libB libA )

add_library( libC STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LibA2.c )
add_executable( APP ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/App.cpp)

target_link_libraries( APP libB libC )
```

This leads to linker errors, even though I feel the calls are not ambiguous.  Am I missing something to make linking a private affair?  Or can you just not do it.

Comment: Your notation is a little weird. A -> B usually means "A depends on B". Which means that libB -> libA seems fine. libB -> App means "libB depends on App", which is not what your text says (and this would be odd, anyway).

Comment: Good catch.  This was actually an error, and inconsistent with the rest of the question.

Comment: A suggestion I've heard elsewhere is to wrap the libraries in namespaces.  Unfortunately, the libraries are 3rd party code.  Is there any way to do this without modifying the source of libA/libC?

Comment: @Michael Smith `namespace libA { #include <libA.h> }`

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Unfortunately, that does not work.  In this instance, both LibB and App use Lib2A's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you describe only those parts of libA that libB needs will end up in libB (and thus in the app), so unless libB uses all of libA it is not the same as the app depending on libA (because in that case all of libA would be available to the app to call, where with what you describe if app were to try calling something from libA that libB does not use you would get an unresolved external error).

Comment: So that is to say if libA had functions A1, A2, An, and lib B had functions B1, B2, Bn.  And libB used functions A1, but nothing else, in this situation, A1 is linked into App, even though it is never directly called by App, but it is only called in libB?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the linker.

For most Unix linkers, link ordere matters; the object needing a symbol must come before the object providing the symbol on the link command line.
 Some linkers (like the one Microsoft provides) don't care.

In any case; if you always link objects in the order of objects needing symbols before those providing it, you'll be fine with any linker.

Comment: While that sounds like a set of problems on its own, I think my question is more along the lines of "Does this roll into a giant Katamari, or can you call functions that are only directly linked to"

Comment: @Michael Smith huh? How is that different from what I answered? What are you *really* asking?

Comment: I added a lot more to the problem description above that gives a working example of the reason why I care.